# Fastest way to determine the length of longest string for a column across lists

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 5000 keys who's values are lists, I need to determine quickly the length of the longest string for a given index in all of the dictionary values

```
index = 1
d = {'foo': ['abc', 'defg'],
     'bar': ['hij', 'klmno']}
#m = len(max(d.values()[index],key=len))?
```

expected output: `5`, because of all of the values at index 1 (`'defg'` and     'klmno'`, the latter is the longest).

Comment: What's wrong with the commented code (which should be `len(max(d[index] ,key=len))`)? What does it matter how many keys the dictionary has if you are looking for a specific key anyway? Python dict lookup time is O(1)

Comment: @DeepSpace The problem with the commented-out code is that "d.values()[index]" is invalid (Py3) or does not do what you expect (Py2).

Comment: @MathiasRav of course, missed that :) `len(max(d[index] ,key=len))`

Comment: Are you asking for the length of that string, or the string itself?

Comment: Also, your expected output should be `4`, not `5`.

Comment: @DeepSpace: no, `klmno` is 5 characters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP asked for certain "index" (which should be "key" actually). and used `index = 1` in their code. The longest string in the value of `d[1]` is `'defg'` which is 4.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, OPs wording `I need to determine quickly the longest string for a given index in all of the dictionary values` is a bit misleading.

Comment: @DeepSpace: no, `index` is the index into each list. There are two lists, `['abc', 'defg']` and `['hij', 'klmno']`. Taking index 1 in each gives you a sequence of `'defg'` and `'klmno'`.

Comment: @DeepSpace: that's what *a given index in all of the values* means here, indexing each list first, then taking the longest string from all those index operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a generator expression to extract the right index:

```
longest_string = len(max((row[index] for row in d.values()), key=len))
```

If all you need is the length, not the string itself, you may as well get the length in the generator expression:

```
highest_length = max(len(row[index]) for row in d.values())
```

Demo:

```
>>> index = 1
>>> d = {'foo': ['abc', 'defg'],
...      'bar': ['hij', 'klmno']}
>>> max((row[index] for row in d.values()), key=len)
'klmno'
>>> max(len(row[index]) for row in d.values())
5
```

You can't escape having to iterate over all values in the dictionary however.

Answer (score 1):

First, extract all the strings of interest with a list comprehension:

```
xs = [v[index] for v in d.values()]
```

Next, take max over the lens of the strings:

```
print(max(map(len, xs)))
```

Comment: Why create a whole list object first? Use a generator expression instead. Also, why not just put the `len()` calls into the values `xs` outputs, why the additional `map()`?

Comment: Indeed, it is probably faster to use a generator expression. Creating a list allows OP to examine the computation at the REPL. There's more than one way to skin a cat. If speed or space usage is a concern, remember to profile against a realistic input (that is, realistic according to OP's use case which is unknown to us).

Answer (score -1):

You're pretty close, you just need to use a generator expression to iterate over all items in the list.

```
print max(len(max(d[i],key=len)) for i in d)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but this is not a list comprehension. It's a generator.

Comment: @HugoSadok  Thanks, that was a mental typo.  Thanks. Updated.

Comment: This is taking the maximum from each list first, then the maximum from those results. The OP is trying to get the max from a given *column*, indicated by `index`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh.